# No puedo instalar nodemon

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Trabajo con **Visual Studio Code** y acabo de instalar Nose.js y luego he introducido en el terminal

`npm install -g nodemon`

pero me aparece esta respuesta:

`"npm" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.`

¿Qué debo hacer?

Comment: debes agregar `C:\Program Files\nodejs` al path de windows!

Comment: Como lo instalaste?

Comment: Puede que este video te sirva https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7l46C_T3otQ&ab_channel=divcode

Answer (score 0):

Lo que está diciendo el error es que no reconoce npm, npm se instala cuando se instala node.

**Los pasos pare resolverlo podrían ser:**

- Desinstalar por completo Node si la versión instalada es la versión
  **Current**.
- Reinstalar Node la versión **LTS**. Es la recomendada por el sitio oficial y la de mayor período de soporte, link a descarga:
  https://nodejs.org/dist/v18.12.1/node-v18.12.1-x64.msi
- Agregar la ruta de node a la variable path en las variables de
  entorno de Windows, para eso en general es suficiente con abrir el
  buscador donde está el botón de inicio de Windows y escribir la palabra **variable**, ahí aparecerá el editor, luego se selecciona la variable path, se presiona el botón edit y se agrega una nueva ruta que sería la de node, en general es algo como: `C:\Program Files\nodejs`. Se puede corroborar antes por las dudas en el explorador de archivos.

En caso de no lograr acceder a las variables de entorno de esa manera, busca como acceder a variables de entorno en la versión de sistema operativo que tenga tu PC. Pueden haber pequeños cambios.

Tras haber agregado la ruta y aceptado todo, se debe reiniciar el PC y volver a intentar correr **npm**, ya debería estar funcionando.

Answer (score -1):

Te recomendaría que verifique que la ruta en la cual instalaste nodejs se encuentre agregada al PATH de tu sistema operativo, si estas en windows, solo escribe variables de entorno en la barra de búsqueda que aparece en el menú de inicio, y posteriormente buscar la variable llamada PATH, a la cual das editar y agregas un nuevo registro con la ruta, y por otro lado si estas en alguna distro Linux podrías usar el .bashrc o .bash_profile que se encuentra en tu home y adicionar la ruta a tu PATH.

Comment: No entendí absolutamente nada. Añadir variables de entorno me suena a chino.